# Active Directory in a home environment?

Tags: active-directory, windows-domain

I have two questions for you all... If I had a standard home router (Netgear R6300) and was looking at running a basic home domain using Active Directory as the domain controller.

1) How do I go about dealing with DHCP: I understand AD works best when it's allowed to control DHCP entirely, however, with my current setup I'm not sure how viable this is... My idea at the moment is to have the Router deal with DHCP of non-AD binded devices, ie: mobile phones, tablets, PS3, TV, etc and then run another DHCP server with Active Directory with a scope that wont overlap. The reason why I am thinking this is because I can't see a way AD will know to give these nonbinded devices IP's without this? What are the pros/cons of my idea? Is there a better solution with my current hardware?

2) AD binded Laptops -- how will these react when taken away from the domain and connected to a new network? Will there be log in issues so they require local accounts? Or will they be able to login to domain accounts without network access? To put it into perspective... For example, how would taking a home Laptop to a friends house and connecting to their Wifi go?

Cheers, I appreciate any help I can get, this is more of a learning project if anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are very unfamiliar with how DHCP works.

The answer is quite simple though. I'll give 2 posisble options. A recommended solution and an alternative solution.

## Recommended solution

Disable DHCP on your router completely and install it on the server.

## Alternative solution

Do not install a DHCP server on the AD server and keep using the router, ignoring the warning that AD gives you during install. Make sure you give the server a static IP outside of the DHCP scope of the router. Also make sure you point the DNS server to the server IP on your router, or your clients will have trouble finding the server.

## Background information

A DHCP server broadcasts through the network that it is a DCHP server, so whenever any device connects to the router, and DHCP is disabled on the router, the device will automatically find the DHCP server on the server itself and gets the IP it needs from there. An AD server can function in both ways, but when the DHCP server is not available for some reason, things can go bad. When the server runs the DCHP server, it will know when thigns stops working and keeps that in mind. In addition, misconfigurations are less likely to happen, because the server knows what to keep in mind.

Comment: You didn't replied to the question. Also, anditpainsme is configuring something like a lab environment, so it's not a good idea to rely only on one DHCP configuration. Usually, a lab environment is totally separated from other environment, even at home.

Comment: The DHCP server on a server is a separate component and has nothing to do with AD itself. AD just wants to be able to get the information from the DHCP server in order to query the pc's etc. The DHCP server is a server on its own, just like the one in the router, with the only difference that AD has access to it.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. I see now my initial concern was a null point. My initial concern was that non-windows devices (such a wireless phones) might receive 169.x.x.x addresses, since they are not AD bound. Thinking about it, the device would never get an address via DHCP if it had to be bound first...silly me.

Comment: As I said, it's the best design, always recommended in a lab environment. You should never mix a home and a lab environment. Also, using two DHCP configuration will allow you to configure specific options for your domain (PXE, alternate DNS, etc...). If you only use your home DHCP, you will have to change the DNS option to bind to the domain DNS. If your lab goes wrong, no device will be able to connect the internet, as DNS will be unreachable.

Comment: @Ob1lan As far as I understand, he wants his non-AD devicves be able to access the server too, otherwise I misunderstood. But either case, unless there are 2 routers in place, the one router DHCP will issue IP's to all devices, and the server DHCP will not issue out any ip adresses.

Comment: Non-AD devices don't need to contact the server, only the Internet, which will be provided by the router. DHCP should assign DNS/IP for use. Correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: A Router will only route traffic. It usually says: the DNS server is located at the ISP, and routes all DNS traffic to your ISP to be resolved. Given that your ISP doesn't know where your server is, Server requests fail. A DNS server on your server would essentially do the same. It first checks for a set of known domain names and if matched, issue the respected IP, and if not, it will forward the DNS to the DNS server from your ISP, to get the internet IP.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I guess the best thing for me to do is to do some more reading and to experiment a little before I attempt to implement anything. :)

Answer (score 1):

1) The best design would be to create two separate subnets. For instance, your home router could have the 192.168.1.0 subnet, and your AD domain could have the 192.168.10.0 subnet.

If your AD devices need to have internet access, you could install a router that will separate the two subnets. Then you can have a DHCP server in your domain, and another one in your home subnet. As router blocks DHCP traffic (broadcast), no home device will ask an IP address to your AD DHCP server. And vice versa. Note you can [setup a basic router using Windows Server (Routing role)](http://blog.mpecsinc.ca/2012/10/lab-using-windows-server-2008-r2-as.html). Or you could use a Linux-like appliance, that also have other roles (VPN, Firewall, Proxy, etc...).

2) By default, when a domain computer can't join the domain to validate credentials, it uses [cached credentials](http://windowsitpro.com/windows/domain-credential-caching). That means, if a users has already logged into this computer, he should be able to logon even if the computer is outside the domain network. Alternatively, you are always able to use a local account.

Comment: I really not recommend using multiple subnets, because devices will simply not be able to talk with eachother. Only one DHCP server will issue the IP, not two, so this will give much more trouble than providing an easy solution.

Comment: As I said, it's the best design, always recommended in a lab environment. You should never mix a home and a lab environment. Also, using two DHCP configuration will allow you to configure specific options for your domain (PXE, alternate DNS, etc...). If you only use your home DHCP, you will have to change the DNS option to bind to the domain DNS. If your lab goes wrong, no device will be able to connect the internet, as DNS will be unreachable.

Comment: I agree with Ob1lan, and is how I have set up previous 'lab' environments, with routing between the subnets

Comment: Question, where do you guys see that this is about a lab environment? All the title says is using AD in a home network.

Comment: If it's an installation at home, it sure is a lab. You know, you try things, you revert when something is wrong. Not like in a real production environment. Thus it's kinda a lab. By the way, we could discuss about this for long. @anditpainsme, do as you want. If you do mistakes, you will learn from them. Is something in your design generates problems, you will have to learn how to deal will them. Enjoy playing with AD !

Comment: To assume a lab situation is really quite presumptuous if the question does not specify it, and it doesn't really look like it on first hand. Also, do you have windows server licences lying around in spades? Unless you have access to MSDN or something, that would be quite far fetched for the average consumer IMO.